# Outlook hangs when left on for a long time

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I have outlook 2019 installed on a windows 10 pro machine. The issue I am having is that when I leave the machine running overnight outlook seems to close but is left running visible on task manager. This also prevents me from opening outlook until I kill the old process. I tried looking into event logs but didn't find any error related to outlook.

Comment: Does this happen when running `outlook.exe /safe` (to disable all add-ins)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating Office?

It's in the menu at the top-left side of the application, under Account. Not the most intuitive place to put it.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I am having is that when I leave the machine running overnight outlook seems to close but is left running visible on task manager.

Does this issue happen every time you left on for a long time? Or it just happens randomly?
Do other users in your working environment have the same issue as you?
In order to conduct further researches on your issue, please provide me with more information related to your issue.

Besides, I did some research about the Outlook process issue and found some possible causes, please check the information in [this article](https://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-exe-continues-running-after-you-exit-outlook/) and see if they could help.